# How to formally express a function defined on unit disk?

Tags: calculus, fourier-series, polar-coordinates

Let $D$ be the unit disk, i.e. $D=\{(x,y): x^2+y^2\le1\}$. Let $f\colon D\to \mathbb R$ be a function.

I associate to $f$ a new function $F\colon [0,1]\times [0,2\pi]\to \mathbb R$ such that

- $F(r,\theta)=f(r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta)$ for all $(r,\theta)\in [0,1]\times [0,2\pi]$;
- $F(0,\theta)$ is indepdente from $\theta\in [0,2\pi]$
- $F(r,0)=F(r,2\pi)$ for all $r\in [0,1]$

If $f\in L^2(D)$ then $F(r,\cdot)\in L^2([0,2\pi])$ because
$$ \int_D |f(x,y)|^2 dxdy=\int_0^1 rdr \int_0^{2\pi} |F(r,\theta)|^2d\theta\,.$$
As $F(\cdot,0)=F(\cdot,2\pi)$, I can expand $F(\cdot,\theta)$ in Fourier series. So I obtain
$$ F(r,\theta)=\sum_{n\in \mathbb Z} f_n(r)e^{in\theta}$$
for some $(f_n(r))_{n\in\mathbb Z}\in \ell^2(\mathbb Z)$.

Is this expansion valid?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes. Check the book of Stein and Weiss "Introduction to Euclidean harmonic analysis", there is a chapter dedicated to this formula and to its generalization to higher dimension. Of course the main point is to give an explicit expression of the $f_n$ and study their properties. WARNING: your reasoning only tells you that $F(r, \cdot)\in L^2(0, 2\pi)$ for almost all $r>0$.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I have another question: if $f$ is continuous, then last two conditions for $F$ are superfluous, am I right?

Comment: What? You always have those two conditions, regardless of the continuity of $f$. If you want $F$ to be continuous in $r$ and $\theta$, then you need continuity.

Comment: I believed that, for example, the condition $F(0,\theta)=cost$ would follow from the upper condition if $f$ were continuous since $\lim_{r\to0} f(r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta)=f(0,0)$.  
PS. I didn't found the book you quoted. I have only found "Introduction to fourier analysis on euclidean spaces"

Comment: That's the book! I remembered the wrong title :-) Concerning the other part, in older books you will find these conditions as saying that $f$ is "single-valued". Which is redundant, today we assume that all functions are single-valued by definition. There is no continuity needed here. For example, $F(0, \theta)=f(0,0)$ for all $\theta$ and that's it, this holds whether $f$ is continuous or not.

Comment: Though not every function is identically equal to its Fourier series. The conditions which make this true, or true almost everywhere, will just need to be evaluated on $\theta \mapsto F(r, \theta)$ for a given $r$.

Answer (score 1):

This has been essentially answered in comments to the main question. Summarizing, the expansion is valid. For more information on this problem and its higher-dimensional generalizations, see "Introduction to Fourier analysis on Euclidean spaces" of Stein and Weiss, chapter IV: "Symmetry properties of the Fourier transform".